Excel spill range reference in Google sheets
Let's say I have a spreadsheet with the following data in it:
       A    B

1      1    1
2      1    1

Now, in cell C1 I am going to add in the formula =A1:A2. Now my data looks like this:
       A    B    C

1      1    1    1
2      1    1    1

In cell D1 I enter in =C1 it will give me the value 1, for example:
       A    B    C     D

1      1    1    1     1
2      1    1    1

And in cell E1 if I enter in =C1# it will give me the dynamic reference contained in that cell, rather than the value of the cell itself, giving the following:
       A    B    C     D     E

1      1    1    1     1     1
2      1    1    1           1

How would I do that same thing in Google Sheets since it doesn't allow the reference of # suffix to reference the range contained in that cell?
I really couldn't find good documentation on this from Microsoft so here is the best reference I could find: https://www.xelplus.com/excel-hash-sign-formulas/.
Related: https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/vmtuzf/does_google_sheets_have_a_spill_reference_method/
Another example:


=A1:B2 from your second step duplicates the entire matrix and doesn't just add one column, did you mean something like =A1:A2?

@Michal sorry that was a typo I fixed it.

@David542 You can't do that on google sheet. There are few work arounds. You may try =D7:INDEX(F7:F,COUNTA(F7:F)).

Google Sheets spills array formula and array expression results, but the hash sign notation is not supported currently (December 2024.)
To get a multi-cell range, use an { array expression }, like this:
={ D7:F9 }

To get a subset of an array, use filter(), array_constrain(), chooserows() or choosecols(). For example, to get the last column in the range D7:F9, use this:
=choosecols(D7:F9, -1)

See
arrayformula(),
array_constrain(),
filter(),
chooserows() and
choosecols().

what if the reference is A1:C4 ? For example, like this: https://gyazo.com/2fda366d1c9d971a47132aaf0751364b

Edited the answer. It's now unclear what your asking. See How do I ask a good question?
